# How to get a menu appearing directly below parent li

Tags: html, css

Hi i thought this would be simple but i have been trying for ages. All i want is a menu across the top and then below a the submenu appearing in the center of its parent.

I have provided an example...

http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/HA5jJ/2/

The reason it wont center is because the length of the parent li is determined by the length of characters and can not be a fixed width. The minus margin works but then will mess up the look of the other sub menu.

About us on the example looks fine but then our services doesn't

help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/HA5jJ/3/

I made some changes to your absolute positioning: `left:50%; margin-left: -64px;` and also your parent `<li>` has now `position:relative;`